# Wordpress website down after update

Tags: php, wordpress

I just received an email that my wordpress website has been updated to:

WordPress 4.3.3.

Now when I go to my domain I receive the message:

```
Guru Meditation:

XID: 1182111921

Varnish cache server
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: Varnish must have something cached that doesn't agree with the updated WordPress. If you have access to, I'd try restarting the Varnish service as a first step.

Answer (score 0):

Clear your cache or if you don't know how to do that then use a private browser or different browser.
If that does not work then hope you have a backup and restore it and wait for WordPress to fix the bugs.